# Swift: draw image and border using UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions

Tags: swift, core-graphics, draw, uigraphicscontext

I need to draw an image like this
[image]

What provided is: green bubble with down arrow image(green bubble image already have border so I don't need to draw it) and center photo. And I need to draw white border around the photo + rounded corner it
This is the code I have so far:

```
let rect = CGRect(origin: .zero, size: CGSize(width: 60, height: 67))
    let width = CGFloat(50)
    let borderWidth: CGFloat = 1.0

    let imageRect = CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: width, height: width)
    let bubbleImg = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "pinGreen")

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(rect.size, false, 0.0)

    let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()

    bubbleImg.draw(in: rect)

    let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: imageRect.insetBy(dx: borderWidth / 2, dy: borderWidth / 2), cornerRadius: width/2)
    context!.saveGState()
    path.addClip()

    image.draw(in: imageRect)
    context!.restoreGState()

    UIColor.purple.setStroke()
    path.lineWidth = borderWidth
    path.stroke()

    let roundedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    let img = roundedImage?.cgImage!
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

and this is the result

[image]

Can anyone help me with this? 
Is there anyway to design and get this type of image from xib file?

Answer (score 2):

I will tell you the simplest way:

1. You need imageView1 for green bubble image, imageView2 for the photo (width=height). Their centers are the same.
2. The imageView2 has corner radius equal to its frame width/2.
3. Set border color of imageView2's layer to White, and border width is about 5 px. Dont forget to set `maskToBounds=true`.

Please try.

---

DaijDjan: this answer in one image (showing IB + code + app): 
[image]

Comment: likely though --  you should / need to draw it with UIGraphics.. your question was quite concrete ;)